# Creating a function that changes values in a list based on probability

Tags: python, python-3.x, bitwise-operators

I'm new to python (or programming for that matter). I'm looking to create a def function with two parameters: a list of bits, and an error probability.

For each element in the list of bits, there is a chance (error probability) that the element should be flipped from 0 to 1 or vice versa. The function should return the new list that contains the bits and the actual number of bits that were flipped.

I've been experimenting for about an hour and a half and couldn't really come up with anything. I know we're supposed to use the function random.random and a for loop inside the def function, but nothing has really worked.

The result should look something like this:

`>>>x
[0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0]`

```
>>>(NewList,FlipTimes)=TheFunction(x,0.2)
>>>NewList
[0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1]
>>>FlipTimes
3
```

Again, I'm very new to programming, so my attempt here is pretty futile.

`def addNoise(a,b):`

```
c=0
for x in a:
    y=random.random
    if y<b:
        if x==1:
            x=0
        else:
            x=1
    for i in x:
        if y<b== True:
            c+=1
return(x,c)
```

Comment: Actually, what is the input? What have you tried? Could you show some code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import random

def flipbit(x, prob):
    count = 0
    out = []
    for e in x:
        if random.random() <= prob:
            count += 1
            out.append(int(not e))
        else:
            out.append(e)
    return out, count


x = [0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1]
new_list, flip_times = flipbit(x, 0.2)
print ('original: ', x)
print ('new list: ', new_list)
print ('flip times: ', flip_times)

# original:  [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1]
# new list:  [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]
# flip times:  2
```